# What kernel does Ubuntu Studio 14.04 use?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-studio

Is it the "rt kernel", the "lowlatency kernel" or the "realtime kernel"? I can't find any source that specifies (weird!). However some sources say that in 13.10 the used kernel was the lowlatency kernel. Is it the same for 14.04?

Comment: Now I'm no expert but you may find this article useful, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio. Under 'Feature Changes for 14.04 LTS'.

Comment: @Xweque yes it is! actually boon has this link in his answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Studio 14.04 comes with the low latency kernel.

---

### Feature Changes for 14.04 LTS

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio

> "**linux-lowlatency** is now merged with **linux-generic** master branch, which means the two are almost identical feature wise. **linux-lowlatency** continues to be configured for preemtiveness and irq threading and depends on the rtirq script."

---

### Ubuntu Studio 14.04 LTS

http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Linux-Distributions/Ubuntu-Studio-Trusty-Tahr-103368.shtml

> "You should also know that Ubuntu Studio comes with a **low-latency kernel**, which allows for high-quality audio production. We recommend this Ubuntu flavor for all your multimedia production needs."

Comment: looks like I'm not so good at searching. thanks XD